# How to find a record in another table recorded at the nearest time in a subquery aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, aggregate

```
select sl.*,

       (select pnd_invoiceno 
        from   PINVDET 
        where  PND_INVNO = sl.invno and

               abs(DATEDIFF(ss, pnd_date, sl.adjustedon)) = 
               (select min(abs(DATEDIFF(ss, pnd_date, sl.adjustedon)))
                from   PINVDET
                where  pnd_invno = sl.invno))

from   vwstocklog sl where sl.invno in (select invno from vwStockDiff) 
order  by sl.invno, sl.adjustedon
```

When I run the above query I get the error:

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

I understand it's saying that the expression `min(abs(DATEDIFF(ss, pnd_date, sl.adjustedon)))` is the problem because it references `sl.adjusted` on in the `min()` aggregate, and it cannot do so unless it's the only column referenced in the aggregate expression.  What I'm not sure about is how to go about fixing it.

What I'm attempting to do here is find the `pnd_invoiceno` value on the record in `pinvdet` with the `pnd_date` value nearest to `sl.adjustedon` for the same item (and I recognize that this has the possibility of linking to multiple records).

Any ideas on how I might adjust this query to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second attempt (filter first):

```
With x as (
    select
        sl.invno,
        sl.adjustedon,
        p.pnd_invoiceno,
        rank() over (
            partition by sl.invno 
            order by abs(datediff(ss, p.pnd_date, sl.adjustedon))
       ) rk
    from
        vwstocklog sl 
            inner join
        pinvdet p
            on p.pnd_invno = sl.invno
    Where 
        Exists (
            Select
                'x'
            From
                vwStockDiff sd
            Where
                sl.invno = sd.invno
        )
)
Select
    x.invno,
    x.adjustedon,
    x.pnd_invoiceno
From
    x
Where
    x.rk = 1
order by 
    x.invno, 
    x.adjustedon
```

First attempt:

```
With x as (
    select
        sl.invno,
        sl.adjustedon,
        p.pnd_invoiceno,
        rank() over (
            partition by sl.invno 
            order by abs(datediff(ss, p.pnd_date, sl.adjustedon))
       ) rk
    from
        vwStockDiff sd
            inner join
        vwstocklog sl 
            on sl.invno = sd.invno
            inner join
        pinvdet p
            on p.pnd_invno = sl.invno
    )
Select
    x.invno,
    x.adjustedon,
    x.pnd_invoiceno
From
    x
Where
    x.rk = 1
order by 
    x.invno, 
    x.adjustedon
```

If you happen to have two times that are an equal distance away, this will return a row for both. Replace `rank()` with `row_number()` if you'd only like 1.

SQLFiddle doesn't seem to be working at the moment, so I can't test this. There's probably syntax errors.

Comment: Brilliant... runs a little slower than I'd like but it works and that's the important thing.  Thanks.

Comment: And no there weren't any mistakes :)

Comment: @BVernon I expect you could speed this up with the correct indexes. However, I'm assuming `vwstocklog` and `vwStockDiff` are views, so it won't be trivial.

Comment: Well I just realized you joined vwStockDiff and vwStockLog instead of selecting rows in vwStockLog where the invno is in vwStockDiff.  invno isn't a unique field in vwStockDiff so that should help some when I fix that.

Comment: Although the main thing about your query that makes it slow is the fact that it's joining every record in pinvdet with the same invno value (of which there will be tons) and then filtering out the ones we don't want.  It would be preferable if we could locate the one we want first and then just join to that I'd think... not sure how to do that though other than the failed attempt in my post.